# embedding external fonts into pdf-file

Tags: fonts, pdf, ghostscript

the acroreader is showing missing fonts in one pdf-file (WPMathB,WPMathA
WP Greek Helve, ...) which can be easily downloaded from http://www.fontpalace.com.

However, the ghostscript command fails, though it is points to the missing fonts directory, `/home/user/WP_ttf_fonts`:

```
 $ gs -o file-with-embedded-fonts.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dEmbedAllFonts=true  -sFONTPATH="/home/user/WP_ttf_fonts" input-without-embedded-fonts.pdf
Page 35    
Can't find CID font "WPMathB".    
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Identity for /WPMathB, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.    
Loading a TT font from 
/usr/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf to emulate a CID font Adobe-Identity   **** Warning: can't process font stream, loading font by the name.    
 ... Done.    
Can't find CMap Identity-UTF16-H building a CIDDecoding resource.     
Can't find CID font "WPMathB".    
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Identity for /WPMathB, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.    
Loading a TT font from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf to emulate a CID font Adobe-Identity
**** Error reading a content stream.     
The page may be incomplete.    
   **** File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.    
 ... Done.
```

Any help, how to tell ghostscript to accept these fonts, please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WPMathA etc. is from Correl Word Perfect and Correl allows you download those fonts (although I didn't find any license in the self-extracting zip archive).  Don't fear the *.exe as it works just fine if you unzip it.  The FILE name for the WP MathA font is Wphv06na.ttf and it doesn't get less gruesome.

Example:

```
sudo chown $USER /usr/local/share/fonts/
cd /usr/local/share/fonts/
wget http://www.corel.com/akdlm/6763/downloads/WordPerfect/wpwin/9/wpfonts.exe
unzip wpfonts.exe
sudo chown -R root /usr/local/share/fonts/
sudo fc-cache
```

The next hurdle is that the PDF has `WPMathA` but the font cache has `WP MathA`:

```
fc-list | grep local.*MathA
/usr/local/share/fonts/Wphv06na.ttf: WP MathA:style=Normal
fc-list -v | grep -c WPMathA
0
```

Your mission is to create the missing configuration files with the required aliases to tie `WPMathA` to `WP MathA`.  After that you can relax by building an aircraft carrier out of toothpicks.

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/fontconfig/
echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>' > ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf
xmlcopyeditor ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf
```

insert:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<!-- $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fontconfig/fonts.conf for per-user font configuration -->
<fontconfig>
  <alias>
    <family>WPMathA</family>
    <prefer><family>WP MathA</family></prefer>
  </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

Don't forget to rebuild the cache again. Didn't need root/sudo for me.

```
fc-cache
```

By this time acroread has stopped complaining about the missing WPMathA and the ghostscript bugzilla bug 687595 has a comment that fontconfig support was added in 8.60 but I guess they lied.  If you still insist on creating a PDF with the embedded font even though the one you have should be working by now you can read ghostscript bugzilla bug 692001 which I will quote right here:

> Comment 2 Ken Sharp 2011-02-28 11:44:42 PST
>
> There are 2 ways to do this:
>
> 1) Locate a genuine CIDFont named Arial, place it in
>   gs/Resource/CIDFont and then tell Ghostscript to use disk files as
>   well as the built in file system. This is done with the -I command
>   line switch (eg -I/gs/Resource).
>
> 2) Use a TrueType font as a replacement. To do this you need to edit
>   gs/Resource/Init/cidfmap and add an entry for the font (Arial),
>   specifying the TrueType font to be used instead and some other
>   parameters. You must then also tell Ghostscritp [sic] to use the
>   specified file, again using the -I switch as above.
>
> You can also use an existing CIDfont with a different name as a
>   replacement by specifying this in the cidfmap file.
>
> Please refer to the documentation in :
>   /gs/doc/Use.htm
>
> Look for "CID fonts" and "CID font substitution".

You will have to `apt-get install ghostscript-doc` to get the `file:///usr/share/doc/ghostscript-doc/Use.htm` Ken refers to.

The file to update is `/var/lib/ghostscript/fonts/cidfmap` just add this line `/WPMathA << /FileType /TrueType /Path (/usr/local/share/fonts/Wphv07na.ttf) /SubfontID 0 /CSI [(Identity) 0] >> ;`

And run `gs -o embedeed-font.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dEmbedAllFonts=true -I/usr/local/share/fonts/Wphv06na.ttf no-embedded-font.pdf`

Please read `file:///usr/share/doc/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html` for background information. It will tell you to please see XDG Base Directory Specification for more details because there you will find the defaults for the $XDG... series of environment variables none of which are set to anything on 14.04 as far as `ps axwwe` shows.